# How to create django queryset by reusing model instances and not performing additional DB query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my project I have the following setup. It has Project and EntryStatus models. Each project has it's own set of Statuses. When user creates a new Project, then I have to create default statuses for this project.

Here is the code for my model manager.

```
class EntryStatusManager(models.Manager):
    def create_default_for_project(self, project: Project):
        for status in self.get_queryset().filter(project=None):
            status.id = None
            status.project = project
            status.save()
```

I want to return a queryset from this method that will contain all of the created statuses. The easiest solution is to make additional query like this

```
def create_default_for_project(self, project: Project):
    created_ids = []
    for status in self.get_queryset().filter(project=None):
        status.id = None
        status.project = project
        status.save()
        created_ids.append(status.id)
    return self.get_queryset().filter(id__in=created_ids)
```

But is there any way to avoid making additional query and simply reuse created model instances?

Comment: What you want it is not possible, at least if you want the _actual_ instance in the DB. Note the ID of the object it is generated by the DB itself, so how would it be possible to have the list of objects (with IDs) if the IDs are generated on DB level?

You may have an alternative doing `created_objects.append(status)` `return created_objects` but your method will return a _list_, not a _queryset_. It might be enough for you though, but not sure.

Comment: ID is being generated when `save()` called, so, after the line `status.save()` `status.id` will have its newly generated ID. P.S. Why did you posted a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: "ID is being generated when save() called" true, but it is done in the DB itself and not by Django, that is why you need to get back that value. I didn't add it as answer because I'm not sure if using a _list_ it is fine for you

Comment: You should take a look at [how-querysets-are-evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) the .query can be pickled to save the query but will hit the database any time the QuerySet is evaluated.